# Http 503 error while migrating workitems in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I am getting below error while migrating workitems between organiations in azure devops. Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException: HTTP code 503: Service Unavailable ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequestAndGetResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest, WebException& webException)

How to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The tool is unable to get a good response from the server.

This is most likely a corporate network thing, then it could be an ADO thing.